# Поиск наиболее похожего образа из базы портретов

Tags: распознавание-образов

Суть программы в том, что она распознаёт образы людей (на фото), сопоставляет с образами из базы, и находит наиболее похожий из них (не совпадение, а именно наиболее похожий).

С распознаванием образов никогда не работал. Какие языки программирования наиболее подходят для решения этой задачи?

Comment: образы чего? речь o iso каких-нить или картинках?

Comment: @just Это, конечно, флуд, но удержаться не мог. Ответ: русский матерный.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы начал с [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/) - бесплатной библиотеки, которая умеет с картинками делать много чего. И почитать [статью](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/654838/Detect-and-Recognize-Faces-usin), как распознаются лица.

У этой библиотеки есть интерфейс к C/C++, Java (в том числе и версия под андроид), Python и многие другие. Так что можно будет экспериментировать.

Answer (score 3):

Любой из языков высокого ур. хотя можно хоть на брейнфаке))) для начала: [Распознавание капчи php](http://lifeexample.ru/php-primeryi-skriptov/raspoznavanie-kapchi-php.html). А дальше дебри математики, в которые лучше без спец подготовки и вазелина не лезть.