# Распределение фотографии человека

Tags: искусственный-интеллект, распознавание

Приветствую граждан этого форума. Можно ли как-то распределить человека в отдельную папку с помощью программы?У меня есть много фотографий с разными людьми и я хочу каждого из них в отдельную папку,но вручную это будет очень долго.

Comment: ну, тут всё просто: для распределения человеков нужна [распределяющая шляпа](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/ru/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%B0)

Comment: а можно взять пару моих ответов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255138/ и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/295019/ и запилить свое решение